# ngDraggable doesn't work with touch when loaded through require.js

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, google-chrome, requirejs

I'm working on a small angular app that needs drag and drop and needs to work with touch.

I found ngDraggable and it looks pretty much exactly like what I need.

Trouble is I'm constrained to load my dependencies with require.js because of the framework of the thing (long story). I also need to use routes and views.

I modified require.config.js to include ngDraggable like this:

```
paths: {
    'angular': requirejs.cardBaseLibBaseUrl + 'angular/angular',
    'angular-route': requirejs.cardBaseLibBaseUrl + 'angular-route/angular-route',
    // other things
    'ngDraggable': requirejs.cardBaseLibBaseUrl + 'ngDraggable-master/ngDraggable'
},
shim: {
    'angular' : {
        deps: ['jquery'], 
        'exports' : 'angular'
    },
    'angular-route': ['angular'],
    // other things
    'ngDraggable' : {
        deps: ['angular']
    }
```

The div that eventually uses ngDraggable looks like this:

```
<div class="shelf">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td ng-repeat="obj in draggableObjects">
                <div class="slot" ng-drop="true" ng-drop-success="onDropComplete($index, $data, $event)">
                    <table id="card-table">
                        <tr>{{obj.description}}</tr>
                        <tr>
                            <div class="card" ng-class="{'selected': obj.mit_card.selected}" ng-drag="true" ng-drag-data="obj" ng-hide="obj.mit_card==null"
                            ng-click="onCardSelected(obj)">
                                <table>
                                    <tr>
                                        <!-- <td class="vertical-text">{{obj.mit_card.description}}</td>-->
                                        <label class="vertical-text">{{obj.mit_card.spec_id}}</label>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div class="remove-zone" ng-drop="true" ng-drop-success="onRemoveDropComplete($data, $event)">Drag here to remove card</div>
</div>
```

It all works fine in Chrome on PC, but when I try it on Android I can't touch-drag.

The examples that come with ngDraggable work with touch-drag, but they have the ngDraggable.js loaded directly in the html, and everything is used right there.

Any ideas on what's going on?

Edit: I put up a [test repository](https://github.com/adilici/test_ngDraggable_require) . Inside ngDraggable-master, the example-.html are the original examples and they work with touch. The index.html is the entry point for my reinterpretation of example-reorder.html with requireJS. It works with a mouse, but touch is a no-go.

Comment: Have you tried to modify the example to work with require, so that you can be sure it is require that messes things and not something else in your code or setup?

Comment: I did. Same result. With require.js touch doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the problem was indeed with ngDraggable. The latest version on GitHub seems to solve it.